# Reference existing setup of AppSync and Cognito Auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

How can I use cloudformation to spin up new instances of AppSync(DynamoDB)? I'm using Cognito for the authentication. Is there any way to reference the existing setup to duplicate the existing schema and queries?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use the "GetIntrospectionSchema", "ListResolvers", "ListDataSources", & "ListDataSources" APIs to fetch the contents of your previously deployed API and then to transform and output those as a CFN template that you can deploy independently. Doing this would require writing a small script that uses the AWS SDK to make API calls and that then writes the results to a json/yaml file that can be deployed via CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there currently isn't a way to reference existing setup in cfn.